# Global es6 module to store constants in react app - prevent garbage collection

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules, react-state

I would like to store some variables inside a module (export) to be used as constants though out my react app. I would like to avoid context because there is no need for components to re-render and also I need those constants to be used outside my react components.

Where should I do it (where to import it), in order to prevent garbage collection?

One idea I have is to import and re-export it on top of my root component.

EDIT:

To be more precise, there will be a component that will set the constant once (mutate the variable), so that other components or files can access it.

Comment: As long as active references exist to a variable, the variable will not be garbage collected

Comment: This is exactly the question. How would I guarante a reference to exist, as long as my react app runs?

Comment: I'm not sure of this but as far as I'm aware a module's exports won't be garbage collected as long as the module remains loaded and I'm not aware of any way to unload a module once it's been loaded

Comment: @apokryfos I think what you say is the correct answer. I have provided my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into this I found that es6 module spec states:

When import your module  it gets `loaded` => `parsed` => `evaluated` and `cached` (singleton). It also says that when you import modules its value is passed by reference (aka assignment). I didn't find anything mentioning when or how es6 modules are unloaded from that cache.

So that means, when you import a module once, it is there for as long as the program is running, and all modules access its values directly.

reference

- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/
- https://medium.com/@mivanichok/understanding-es6-modules-in-depth-article-b49612926e39

Answer (score 1):

So, what you will need is some sort of setter/getter pattern. Though I mostly don't recommend it unless you know what you are doing, because React **won't re-render if the variable changes** and because of that you need to **be sure the variable is set before it is used**.

You should have something like the example below in order for it to work the way you want. You can find an example of it working on this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowvariable-reference-through-components-4wfl0).

```js
export let MY_VARIABLE = "";

export const setMyVariable = value => (MY_VARIABLE = value);
```

PS: I've added some `console.log` to the code in order for you to see how the import/get/set behaves.

Comment: When the component is unmounted (eg from navigator) isn't this imported module garbage collected?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this would matter? Why is it important for your application that a constant is not garbage collected?

Comment: There is a component that will set a constant once, so that other components or files can access it.

Comment: That is not a constant then, please edit your question with that information and I will update my answer.

Comment: Check the updated answer and the codesandbox implementation to see if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: So how does this guarantee that my variable won't be de-referenced, therefore garbage collected?

Comment: If you import it on your app's entry point then it should stay in the apps memory, then you can update/get the variable wherever you want.

Comment: I don't think importing it on top of entry point this is correct. I have imported it only in loading screen component (which is where I set the variable), and then import it on another component and I can see the correct value.

Comment: Yes it will work on anything above the component that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an config.js inside src folder and write the your constant variable like

//config.js
module.exports = {
  CONST_VAR  : 'const value',
}

import config.js in your component and use it

Comment: When the component is unmounted (eg from navigator) isn't this imported module garbage collected?